# How to splice an object from array of objects?

Tags: node.js, express

The thing is i am doing a array of favorites for each user object.
I did the insert request to the array to add some favorite recipe.
the problem is when i want to remove favorite from the array
its always remove the last object and not the exact object i want.

```
const recipe = await getRecipes(req.params.id); //gives the recipe object
 let user = await User.findById(req.user._id); // gives the user object
  
  console.log(recipe);
  user.recipes.splice(user.recipes.indexOf(recipe), 1);

  await user.save();
  res.send(user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your call to `indexOf` passing the recipe object is not finding the element in the array so it returns `-1`. See how this code works:

```js
let x = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
let obj = {id: 2}
let i = x.indexOf(obj)
// i is -1 since obj isn't in the array. 
// Another object that looks like obj is there, 
// but they aren't the same exact object
console.log("i=",i)  
// This will remove the last since splicing with -1 does that
x.splice( x.indexOf("d"), 1)
console.log(x)

// when the array has objects in it you can use `findIndex`
let y = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
let j = y.findIndex(e => e.id === obj.id)
console.log("j=",j)
y.splice( j, 1 )
console.log(y)
```

So what you want to do is find a reliable way to find the index of the recipe in the array. See the 2nd example for how you can find the index within the object. `Array.findIndex` lets you compare objects in a way that's specific to the object structure.

Comment: the recipe object is an mongo object. with _id, recipeTitle...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the object form the array, you can use filter method like this:

```
user.recipes = user.recipes.filter(r => {
    return r !== recipe;
})
```

Comment: and what then? i will get true or false no?

Comment: No, you will get a new array with all items that pass the test inside the callback.

Comment: and how can i use it? i dont get it